# how to generate random convex quadrilaterals using circles (actually inscribed within circles)?

Tags: graphics, plotting

I would like to generate random convex quadrilaterals using circles, my tutor has suggested to using randomreal to generate 4 numbers and scale the sum of them to 2pi, and then use trigonometry properties to do that, I do not see how that works, can somebody gives some hints about how I should go with it then I can try it out.

Comment: "Use trigonometry" means place them on the unit circle. Then connect the dots.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this way?

```
n = 1000;
x = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {n, 5}];
x[[All, 2 ;;]] *= Divide[(2. Pi), (x.{0., 1., 1., 1., 1.})];
x = x.UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1., {5, 4}]];
quads = Transpose[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {3, 1, 2}];
```

Convexity test:

```
And @@ (Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonConvexQ /@ quads)
```

> True

Comment: maybe we only use random four points on the circle and to construct a quadrilateral?

Comment: Certainly, this is a trivial problem in the sense that it can be tackled in many ways. I just tried to make it fast by using as much vectorized operations and matrix arithmetic as possible. On my machine, the code above generates about 3 million quadrilaterals per second.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[randomQuad]
randomQuad = SortBy[#, ArcTan @@ # &] & /@ RandomPoint[Circle[], {#, 4}] &;

SeedRandom[777]
Graphics[{Circle[], 
  {Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[Gray], RandomColor[], Polygon@#} & /@ randomQuad[5]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun way to use Henrik's stuff (and some other nicely vectorized operations):

```
n = 550;
x = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {n, 5}];
x[[All, 2 ;;]] *= Divide[(2. Pi), (x.{0., 1., 1., 1., 1.})];
x = x.UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1., {5, 4}]];
quads = Transpose[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {3, 1, 2}];
disks = {Range[2, 3], Range[7, 8] , Range[12, 15]};
shiftQuads = quads +
   RandomChoice[Flatten@disks, n]*
    Transpose[
     ConstantArray[{Cos[Subdivide[0., 2. \[Pi], n - 1]], 
       Sin[Subdivide[0., 2. \[Pi], n - 1]]}, 4], {2, 3, 1}];

{
  Opacity[.15],
  Annulus[{0, 0}, {-1, 1} + MinMax@#] & /@ disks,
  Thread@{Opacity[.5], RandomColor[n], Thread[Polygon@shiftQuads]}
  } // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I will have a try, so many thanks!